# How to add a Button Function for login in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

So I created a login form and my Button for login isn't working can anyone help me with this? I tried to put OnClickListener but it turns out Red

```
public class login extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText1, editText2; //Deklarasi object dari class EdiText
    String username, password; //Deklarasi object string
    Button login1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("SUNNYSIDE");


    }


    public void login1(View view) {
        //Method onClick pada Button

        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        login1     = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login)
        username = editText1.getText().toString();
        password = editText2.getText().toString();


        //Kondisi jika username dan password benar maka akan menampilkan pesan text toast
        //Login sukses dan masuk ke activity 2
        if ((username.contains("Username")) && ((password.contains("Password")))) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Login Sukses", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if ((username.matches("") || password.matches("")))
      /*
      Atau jika input text 1 dan text 2 kosong
       */ {
            //Maka akan menampilkan pesan text toast
            Toast.makeText(this, "Isikan Username dan Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            //jika kedua kondisi diatas tidak memenuhi

            Toast.makeText(this, "Login Gagal /Username Password Salah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Also if there's something wrong with my coding, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this line `login1     = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login)` to your `onCreate` method.

Rename your `login1` method to something more meaningful that doesn't clash with your `login1` variable name, such as `loginClick`.

Register a listener on your `Button` in `onCreate` with `setOnClickListener()` and override the `onClick` method to just call your `loginClick` method.

UPDATE

Put at the end of your `onCreate` method the following:

```
login1 = findViewById(R.id.login);
login1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             loginClick();
         }
});
```

Comment: Can you write it for me? I have difficulties in placing it

Comment: error: method loginClick in class login cannot be applied to given types;
                    loginClick();
                    ^
  required: View
  found: no arguments

Comment: You're not using the `View` so remove it from the method; no parameters are required. Just `void loginClick() {}`.

Comment: Now it can run, but when I press the button there's nothing happen, I didn't redirect to the page that I set

Comment: Where does it cease working as expected? Is `"Login Sukses"` shown in a `Toast`?

Comment: Nothing happens at all

Comment: Immediately after `password = ...` place the following: `Log.d("test","username = [" + username + "], password = [" + password + "]");` and view the result in Logcat. This will narrow your problem down to the conditional statements that follow.

Answer (score 0):

add this part of code in your onCreate Method :

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("SUNNYSIDE");

        login1 = findViewById(R.id.button_login);
        login1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 loginClick();
             }
        });

    }
```

be sure that your xml view button contains id : `button_login`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_login"
    ... />
```

Comment: I recreate my coding and it works but It didn't work if I put a toast here, it says " error: no suitable method found for makeText(<anonymous OnClickListener>,String,int)
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Login Sukses", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         ^
    method Toast.makeText(Context,CharSequence,int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context)
    method Toast.makeText(Context,int,int) is not applicable
"

Answer (score 0):

Working now, I recreate the whole code to be like this :

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    u = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    p = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    l = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    loginClick();
}
public void loginClick(){
    l.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(u.getText().toString().equals("admin")&&p.getText().toString().equals("admin")){
                Toast.makeText(login.this,"Login Anda Sukses",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(login.this,"Login anda gagal, periksa kembali username dan password anda",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```